# How to handle n number of Multipart files in Spring-boot Rest Controller

Tags: spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I am creating an application wherein there is a form & sub-form.

The form consists of Product Details.
Sub-form consists of Color Details of the Product.

The frontend API request body is shown below.

```
{
  "raw_material_id": 1137,
  "extra_wip": "",
  "is_active": "1",
  "size_ratio_name_id": "45",
  "is_new": 0,
  "created_at": null,
  "mrp": 125,
  "collection": null,
  "hsn_code": "62113300",
  "is_sync": 0,
  "extra_fabric_programming": "",
  "sub_category_name": "INDOWESTERN SET",
  "updated_at": null,
  "category_name": "MENS",
  "is_update": 0,
  "name": "8642",
  "season": null,
  "comment": "",
  "id": 1924,
  "itm_no": "",
  "seasonID": 7,
  "collectionID": 3,
  "raw_material_colors": [
    {
      "color_id": 123,
      "color_name": "test",
      "item_image": (binary) (This is nothing but Multipart File)
    },
    {
      "color_id": 456,
      "color_name": "test1",
      "item_image": (binary) (This is nothing but Multipart File)
    }
  ]
}
```

Content-Type Details:

Content-Disposition: form-data

I am attaching the UI screenshot to help you understand better.

[Application frontend UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgKlk.png)

I want to understand how to handle Images here in Spring boot.

I am also attaching the code that i tried.

```
@PutMapping( value="mainitem/{id}" , consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> user(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable Integer id,@RequestBody MainItem mainItem,
             @RequestPart MultipartFile files) {
        
        
        
        MainItem mainItem2 = mainItemrepo.findById(id).get();
        mainItem2.setId(mainItem.getId());
        mainItem2.setCollection(collectionRepo.collectionForMainItem(mainItem.getCollectionID()));
        mainItem2.setSeason(seasonRepo.seasonForMainItem(mainItem.getSeasonID()));
        mainItem2.setCategory_id(categoryrepo.categoryForMainItem(mainItem.getCategory_name()));
        mainItem2.setSub_category_id(subcategoryrepo.subCategoryForMainItem(mainItem.getSub_category_name()));
        mainItem2.setComment(mainItem.getComment());
        mainItem2.setCreated_at(mainItem.getCreated_at());
        mainItem2.setUpdated_at(mainItem.getUpdated_at());
        mainItem2.setExtra_fabric_programming(mainItem.getExtra_fabric_programming());
        mainItem2.setExtra_wip(mainItem.getExtra_wip());
        mainItem2.setHsn_code(mainItem.getHsn_code());
        mainItem2.setIs_active(mainItem.getIs_active());
        mainItem2.setIs_new(mainItem.getIs_new());
        mainItem2.setIs_sync(mainItem.getIs_sync());
        mainItem2.setIs_update(mainItem.getIs_update());
        mainItem2.setItm_no(mainItem.getItm_no());
        mainItem2.setMrp(mainItem.getMrp());
        mainItem2.setName(mainItem.getName());
        mainItem2.setRaw_material_id(mainItem.getRaw_material_id());
        mainItem2.setSize_ratio_name_id(mainItem.getSize_ratio_name_id());
        mainItemrepo.save(mainItem2);
        //Colors
        for(Map<String, Object> listMap:mainItem.getRaw_material_colors()) {
            System.out.println(listMap.get("color_id").toString());
            System.out.println(listMap.get("color_name").toString());
            System.out.println(listMap.get("item_image").toString());
        }
        

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(new error(200, "Data Edited Successfully", "OK", request.getRequestURI()));

    }
```

Please help me here on how to handle such requests.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

File data cannot be directly included in JSON. It may be possible to use form-data to transfer data and files using different keys, and then match them based on array subscripts or file name.

code:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> user(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable Integer id, 
@RequestPart("jsonData") MainItem mainItem,@RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
}
```

form-data:

```
jsonData:{"data":"data"}
files:(binary1)
files:(binary2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I also concluded with the same answer. I am now sending the data in json format and file differently.